# Referring to (subquery based) alias in further subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I refer to an alias created from a subquery in the FROM clause, in a second subquery in the where clause?

```
Select x FROM 
((SELECT x,y FROM A) UNION (SELECT x,y FROM B) UNION (SELECT x,y FROM C)) AS newAlias 
WHERE y IN (SELECT MAX(y) FROM newAlias)
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure the answer is yes, but either way, you can easily check these things for yourself using SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: No, the answer is no. The `NewAlias` subquery has to be repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the answer is no. The `NewAlias` subquery has to be repeated.

It would be possible with CTEs (Common Table Expressions) but MySQL has not implemented them:

```
WITH newAlias AS
  (SELECT x,y FROM A UNION SELECT x,y FROM B UNION SELECT x,y FROM C)
SELECT x 
FROM newAlias 
WHERE y = (SELECT MAX(y) FROM newAlias) ;
```

In MySQL, you have to repeat the subquery:

```
SELECT x 
FROM 
  (SELECT x,y FROM A UNION SELECT x,y FROM B UNION SELECT x,y FROM C) 
  AS newAlias 
WHERE y = 
      ( SELECT MAX(y) 
        FROM
          (SELECT x,y FROM A UNION SELECT x,y FROM B UNION SELECT x,y FROM C) 
          AS newAlias  
      ) ;
```

Of course, you can usually rewrite-reformulate the query. One way to do that:

```
SELECT x 
FROM 
  (SELECT x,y FROM A UNION SELECT x,y FROM B UNION SELECT x,y FROM C) 
  AS newAlias 
WHERE y = GREATEST( (SELECT MAX(y) FROM A)
                  , (SELECT MAX(y) FROM B)
                  , (SELECT MAX(y) FROM C)
                  ) ;
```